# gradle: how to share a build.gradle which contains information I am the only one to have?

Tags: gradle, sonatype, build.gradle

My build.gradle file contains a section like this to upload archives to SonaType:

```groovy
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            beforeDeployment {
                MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment);
            }

            // HERE
            repository(url: sonatypeRepoURI) { 
                authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername,
                    password: sonatypePassword);
            }

            pom.project {
                // etc etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the point marked `HERE`, other users wishing to use my build file will fail, because at least the first variable is not defined:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/path/to/build.gradle' line: 144

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'whateverTheProject'.
> No such property: sonatypeRepoURI for class: 
  org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

How do I modify the section above so that users are not affected by these variables not being defined for them?

Comment: Here's an example of a build file dealing with this problem: https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/DbSetup/blob/master/build.gradle.

Comment: @JBNizet excellent! I have found another way, but it is really hackish compared to this solution! If you put this as an answer I'll gladly accept this. Still a novice with gradle...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to add all the needed properties to your **gradle.properties** file, which you add to version control, but leave the values empty.

Eg:

```
version=1.0
signing.keyId=
signing.password=
signing.secretKeyRingFile=

sonatypeUsername=
sonatypePassword=
```

Then you override these in your own **${USER}/.gradle/gradle.properties**.
As an example take a look at a working project https://github.com/judoole/monitorino. Should be able to run all tasks at any machine except **snapshot**, **stage** and **build**.

Edit: I would not do it like this today. Follow the Gradle guide, using required. Just as the example from @jb-nizet Gradle ref 53.3.3 Conditional Signing: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I love gradle, but there are too many ways to do things... Comes from the fact of me being a Groovy newbie, I guess!

Comment: Gets better when you get the a little experience with it! And on the extra plusside you get to learn a new and lovely programming language :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple just create the "gradle.properties" file in "~/.gradle" with the following contents:

sonatypeUsername=
sonatypePassword=

After run your project. Its running properly.